# Continuous Delivery for React App using Docker in Jenkins in Windows

Tags: reactjs, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I followed (this)[https://hackernoon.com/continuous-delivery-of-react-app-with-jenkins-and-docker-8a1ae1511b86] tutorial for setting up Continuous Delivery for React App using Jenkins and Docker.I made all initial set up in Jenkins and when i try to build job it shows the following error : -

[image: Jenkins Console Output]

So i understood the docker installation is missing in Jenkins pipeline so i tried to add docker installation in pipeline and added Jenkins installation in tool configuration as well.But still it shows same error any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

This is my Jenkisfile : -

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages{
stage('Checkout') {
    steps{
        script{
            checkout scm
        }
     }
    }
stage('Install dependencies') {
  steps {
    script {
      def dockerTool = tool name: 'docker', type: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool'
               withEnv(["DOCKER=${dockerTool}/bin"]) {
                //stages
                //here we can trigger: sh "sudo ${DOCKER}/docker ..."
                } 
            }
        }
      }
   stage('Environment') {
       steps{
           script{
            sh 'git --version'
            echo "Branch: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
            sh 'docker -v'
            sh 'printenv'
           }
       }
     }
    stage('Build Docker test'){
        steps{
        sh 'docker build -t react-test -f Dockerfile.test --no-cache .'
        }
    }
    stage('Docker test'){
      steps{
      sh 'docker run --rm react-test'
      }
    }
    stage('Clean Docker test'){
      steps{
      sh 'docker rmi react-test'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy'){
    steps{
      if(env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master'){
        sh 'docker build -t reactapp --no-cache .'
        sh 'docker tag reactapp localhost:5000/reactapp'
        sh 'docker push localhost:5000/reactapp'
        sh 'docker rmi -f react-app localhost:5000/reactapp'
      }
    }
    }
  }
 }
```

Dockerfile

```
# Extending image
FROM node:carbon

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get -y install autoconf automake libtool nasm make pkg-config git apt-utils

# Install Docker -y flag suppresses prompting from apt-get
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app  
....
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Jenkins within a Docker container like in that article, you'll need to have Docker installed in that Docker image to run Docker commands.  If Docker is installed, it's likely a permission or PATH issue.

One way you can check if Docker is installed and able to be run is to login to the container Jenkins is running in and try to run a Docker command:

1. `docker ps` - run on the machine that is running Docker will tell you what containers are running. Grab the CONTAINER ID for the Jenkins Docker container.
2. `docker exec -it <put container id here> bash` - will get you a running shell into that container so you can run commands from within the container.
3. `docker -v` - from within the container will tell you if docker has been installed successfully. If you get `docker: command not found` it isn't able to be used by Jenkins.
4. `exit` - will close your shell.

You can install Docker within the Jenkins Docker image by adding `RUN` commands to your Dockerfile. For example:

```
# Install Docker -y flag suppresses prompting from apt-get
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

Docker documentation to install: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1

Comment: @bowlens thanks yes your are right docker installation was missing i added the RUN command to Docker file and even updated permission and now i am getting below error : -

`E: Unable to locate package docker-ce`
`E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli`
`E: Unable to locate package containerd.io`
`E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'containerd.io'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'containerd.io'`
`ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io' returned a non-zero code: 100`

Comment: There are some other commands you may need to run on that Docker documentation page to add the repository and what not. I would try to add those in that RUN block and see what you get.

Comment: thanks for your help kindly let me know the commands once it’s working.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repositoryhttps://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository 

Above where you install is what you'll need to do. You have to add the repository and then running the install should work fine.